# 3 Column CSS Equal Height jQuery solution

Tags: jquery, height

Hey, I was working on a solution to my equal height three columns CSS equal height layout with jQuery, because the CSS workarounds were really giving me some trouble.

I came up with the following code:

```
$('.columns').css("height", "$('#detail').height()");
```

But for some reason, I don't see any effect when I reload my [web page](http://www.marioplanet.com).

I even tried waiting nesting it in a `(window).load()` event handler instead of the `(document).ready()` just to test it out.

I was wondering if it's not possible to set the CSS property of an element as a jQuery statement or something like that.

Or, is it because my height for my `<div id="#detail>` is not set at all.

I also tried setting `#detail` to `height: auto;` but this did not work either.

Please tell me if this is an impossible workaround I'm trying to find here, but hopefully why! :)

Answer (score 1):

Set overflow: hidden; on your #detail div. Also, jQuery's .height() returns a number. CSS requires us to put px at the end. This should work for you.

```
$('.columns').css('height', $('#detail').height() + 'px');
```

Comment: Hmm, let me work it out here, but it seems to be throwing it off, because of the placement.  Although it looks as though this problem has been fixed.

Comment: You could try replacing the overflow: hidden with a clear div after the last floated element in the #detail div.

Comment: Remove the overflow: hidden style from the detail id. Instead, do this.

style: 
.clear {
  height: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  clear: both;
 }

code:
<div id="details">
 <div class="columns">column1 content</div>
 <div class="columns">column2 content</div>
 <div class="columns">column3 content</div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

Comment: I don't think 'px' is required anymore. The latest jQuery just assumes 'px' if you use a number. Check it out.